# When can we choose compact included set inside an open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space,U be an open set inside it.

Given any $x\in U$,when can we choose a neiborhood near $x$ such that $V_x\subset\bar{V}_x\subset U$?with $\bar{V}$ compact

For example does this holds for metric space /complete metric space/compact Hausdorff space is there some general condition?

Comment: This condition is related to [local compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) (in particular, check point 3 in the equivalent conditions under the assumption of Hausdorffness). Compact Hausdorff spaces have this property, but metric spaces will not in general (e.g. an infinite-dimensional normed linear space).

Comment: I show the case for metric space as follows: exist $B_x(\epsilon)\subset U$,then we show $B_x(\frac{\epsilon}{2})\subset\subset B_x(\epsilon)$

Comment: The title mentions "compact".  The text does not.  Which is it?  There are two vastly different questions.  One is $V_x\subset\overline{V}_x\subset U$, no compactness; the other with compactness required.

Comment: But, in certain metric spaces (like the family of examples I gave, or the one GEdgar gave), no closed ball is compact.

Comment: Thanks,I got the first point the charaterization of locally compact Hausdorff space is any neiborhood of $x$ exist compact set included in it.

Comment: The proof seems correct since $\{y\mid \|y-x\|\le \epsilon\}$ is closed set hence closure of $\overline{B_x(\frac{\epsilon}{2})}\subset \{y\mid \|y-x\|\le \frac{\epsilon}{2}\} \subset B_x(\epsilon)$?Since metric is continuous function?

Comment: Ok I got the second question $\{y\mid \|y-x\|\le \epsilon\}$ norm ball need not to be compact in infinite dimension normed linear space hence it need not to be compact included,for otherwise if exist some $V_x\subset \overline{V}_x \subset U$ with $\overline{V}_x$ compact,then exist closed ball inside it,since closed set of compact set is compact,this ball need to be compact contradiction to the fact that ball in NLS  with infinite dimension is not compact

Comment: @user854214 Sorry,I am not sure whether I misinterpret it.   For the metric space , if we remove compact requirement that is $V_x\subset\bar{V}_x\subset U$ always hold but $\overline{V_x}$ can not be compact correct?

Comment: Nothing to do with completeness,since Banach space is complete

Comment: Yes, $\overline{V_x}$ can fail to be compact. For instance, when $X=\Bbb Q$.